# PHP - Parse properties of an Object like an Array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
$json = '{
"Name": "Peter",
"countries": {
    "France": {
        "A": "1",
        "B": "2"
    },
    "Germany": {
        "A": "10",
        "B": "20"
    },
    ....
}
}';
```

I want to parse the properties of the object in the property "countries" like an array. In Javascript I would the lodash function `values`. Is there in PHP any function to do that easily?

Comment: `json_decode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a duplicate.

Here's what you need:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

json_decode parses a json object. The true option tells it to return an associative array instead of an object.

To access the countries info specifically:

```
foreach ($array["countries"] as $ci) {
     //do something with data
}
```

See the manual for more info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

editing to add a good point in another answer:
you can access the key and value with the foreach if you need the country names as well. like so:

```
foreach ($array["countries"] as $country => $info) {
     //do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply parse the string to json using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and use object notation like this:

```
$countries = json_decode($json)->countries;
//do anything with $countries
```

Comment: are you sure about that part of your code: `$json->json_...`?

Comment: @Jeff oops! Thanks!

Comment: countries is not an array. It is an object. I did following:`$data = json_decode($json, true);foreach ($data["countries"] as $info) {`

Comment: @MrScf If you use `json_decode($json, true)` then you get a associative array and hence you can use `echo $info['A']`

Answer (score 1):

`array_keys` does the same basic thing as Lodash's  `_.values` appears to.

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true); // cause you want properties, not substrings :P
$keys = array_keys($obj['countries']);

// $keys is now ['France', 'Germany', ...]
```

In PHP, though, you can get the key and value at the same time.

```
foreach ($obj['countries'] as $country => $info) {
    // $country is 'France', then 'Germany', then...
    // $info is ['A' => 1, 'B' => 2], then ['A' => 10, 'B' => 20], then...
}
```